# Trying to Create Rule to Fire When Someone is Added CiviCRM Group

Tags: drupal, drupal-rules

Using Drupal Rules, I'm trying to create a rule that will fire when someone has been added to a CiviCRM group.

[Here is a blog post from petednz](https://civicrm.org/blogs/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-single-or-multiple-contacts-civi-imports-and-webforms) which describes how to do this when a tag gets added to a CiviCRM contact.

I'm looking for the same thing but with CiviCRM groups, the choice in the Rules' "React on Event" dropdown would look like "CiviCRM Entity Group has been created" but it's not there.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

And to provide a bit more context, I'm creating a Drupal account for the Contact (If they don't have one) and adding the person to a Drupal Organic Groups group.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Shai
Do you have CiviCRM Entity module running? If not does it extend your options?

Comment: Hey Pete, yes CiviCRM Entities is installed and turned on. I used your rule from the blog post as a basis. It's creating a Drupal account and not posting any errors to he Drupal error log. But the og part is just not doing anything.  I posted the rule to a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/f9PRTcYV. Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Shai, this is something that would be useful to publish if you've got it working.

Comment: Shai, did you get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the new CiviRules extension from ErikH and others to do that - see his answer to my question [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3787/how-can-i-send-a-cc-of-an-activity-assignment-e-mail-to-another-user-as-an-fyi)

Comment: Hey, Joe... thanks for letting me know about CiviRules. I didn't know about it. Two issues though: 1. It's only compatible with CiviCRM 4.4 and this site is 4.5. The other thing is that the action I want to take after the condition "contact added to group" has been met is that I want the person added to Drupal Organic Groups group. It doesn't look like that extension can take action on stuff going on in Drupal.